# How to fix Warning: preg_replace(): Empty regular expression?

Tags: php

I use the Modified shop software.

I want to generate a sitemap with a module.

I get the following error message:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Empty regular expression in /www/htdocs/****/*****.de/inc/shopstat_hrefMask.inc.php on line 39

On Line 39:

```
  $newstring  = preg_replace($search,$replace,$newstring);
```

What can I do before this to check whether the request is empty?

Comment: define something in $search ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know it. It is intended to remove "defined characters".

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `$search` is not empty, like this:

```
if (Trim($search) !== '') {
    $newstring  = preg_replace($search,$replace,$newstring);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I still get the same error message.

Comment: @user2750525 unfortunately I mistyped the if in my answer. I have edited it. Can you check it now?